# pushd into folder named + (plus)

Tags: bash

I'm in a bash script looping some folders. One folder is named `+`. When I call `pushd` on that folder I get the message `pushd: +: Ungültige Zahl.` which translates do `invalid number`.

I noticed I can workaround when I call `pushd ./+`. Is it documented behavior?

Comment: BTW, it's not really great form to use `pushd` in scripts at all; it's not POSIX-defined (indeed, the only reference in the spec is in a list of commands for which "the results are unspecified"), and some of its behaviors are in particular not a very good fit for noninteractive use. It's generally better to just scope your directory changes with subshells, or track a prior directory and change back later, when you need to undo them inside the same process at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard `--` posix [utility convention](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) option delimiter.

```
pushd -- +
```

works as expected on bash 4.4.12.

Looking at the [bash pushd builtin sources](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/pushd.def#L221), it stops processing options when `--` options is encountered. Git blame tells me that handling of `--` in the lines `if (ISOPTION (list->word->word, '-'))` in `builtins/pushd.def` in bash sources exists for 23 years since bash 2.0.

Comment: This could be considered a coincidence, as `+N` doesn't necessarily have to have been considered an option.

Answer (score 0):

See `help pushd`:

> pushd: pushd [dir | +N | -N] [-n]
>
> Adds a directory to the top of the directory stack, or rotates
>       the stack, making the new top of the stack the current working
>       directory.  With no arguments, exchanges the top two directories.
>
> `+N` - Rotates the stack so that the Nth directory (counting
>           from the left of the list shown by `dirs', starting with
>           zero) is at the top.

---

So, the documentation for `pushd` states that when it's given a `+`, that's expected to be followed by the number of items in the stack to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

For all cases of having a filename that looks to the shell like an argument, you should simply name the file entry using a different approach. Use the path to it!  `pushd ./+` will work.